# If a discrete and faithful representation of a surface group has proximal values, does the attracting points map have a continuous extension?

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions, geometric-structures

For some context, I'm studying the paper [*Anosov Representations and Proper Actions*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/geometry-and-topology/volume-21/issue-1/Anosov-representations-and-proper-actions/10.2140/gt.2017.21.485.full) [GGKW].

$G$ denotes a non-compact real reductive Lie group of rank greater than $1$, $\Gamma$ denotes the fundamental group of an oriented closed surface of genus greater than $1$, and $\rho : \Gamma \to G$ denotes a faithful representation with discrete image. $P_\theta \subset G$ is a standard parabolic subgroup. This means there's an implicit fixed Cartan decomposition $G = K \exp \bar{\mathfrak{a}}^+ K$, with $\bar{\mathfrak{a}}^+$ denoting a closed positive Weyl chamber with respect to a choice of simple system $\Delta$ of restricted roots $\Sigma$ of a Cartan subspace $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{g}$. And $P_\theta$ is the normalizer in $G$ of the Lie algebra obtained as a direct sum of root spaces over roots in $\Sigma^+ \backslash \mathrm{span}(\Delta \backslash \theta)$, where $\Sigma^+$ denotes the positive roots with respect to $\Delta$. This is all discussed in Section 2.2.2. $g \in G$ is called $P_\theta$-proximal if it has an attracting (at an attracting fixed point $p \in G/P_\theta$, the eigenvalues of the differential map $Dg_p : T_p(G/P_\theta) \to T_p(G/P_\theta)$ have magnitudes less than $1$) fixed point in $G/P_\theta$. Its attracting fixed point is unique (Lemma 2.26 [GGKW]). An element $\gamma \in \Gamma$ has a unique attracting fixed point in $\partial \Gamma \approx \partial \mathbb{H}^2$, and the set of attracting fixed points of elements of $\gamma$ forms a dense subset of $\partial \Gamma$ (Proposition 4.2 (3) of *Boundaries of hyperbolic groups* by Benakli and Kapovich).

**Question:** If $\rho(\gamma)$ is $P_\theta$-proximal for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$, then does the map taking, for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$, the attracting fixed point in $\partial \Gamma$ of $\gamma$ to the attracting fixed point of $\rho(\gamma)$ have a continuous extension to all of $\partial \Gamma$?

I believe the answer is no, so I'm hoping to learn of a counterexample. One difficulty is I don't know of many non-Anosov surface group representations. It seems that the property in Theorem 1.1 (2) of [GGKW] does not imply the property in Theorem 1.1 (1), because the property in Theorem 1.1 (1) has a uniform constant. If it did however, then the answer would be yes. The naive hope I have for the answer possibly being yes is that perhaps there's something special about the case that $\Gamma$ is a surface group, as opposed to an arbitrary hyperbolic group.

Comment: I am still studying this area of mathematics and don't know how difficult/easy this question is. I can produce a more specific question in a particular instance of this framework (which I think makes the question harder to answer, however, given that I expect there to be counterexamples).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are effectively asking about the existence of an analogue of the **[Cannon-Thurston maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon%E2%80%93Thurston_map)** in this setting. Here is a counter-example.  Take $$G=G_1\times G_2=SL(2,{\mathbb C})\times SL(2,{\mathbb C}).$$ Let $\rho_1: \Gamma\to SL(2,{\mathbb R}) < G_1$ be a discrete and faithful embedding corresponding to a uniformization of a surface with the fundamental group $\Gamma$. Let $\rho_2:   \Gamma\to G_2$ be an embedding whose image is dense in $G_2$ and such that the image of every nontrivial element of $\Gamma$ is loxodromic. (It is a nice exercise to prove that such homomorphisms exist by using the Baire Category Theorem.) Then the homomorphism
$$
\rho=(\rho_1,\rho_2): \Gamma\to G
$$
satisfies the hypothesis in your question. I claim that there is no equivariant continuous map of the circle (the ideal boundary of the hyperbolic plane) to the full flag-manifold of $G$, which is $S^2\times S^2$ (the product of flag-manifolds of $G_1, G_2$). Indeed, if such a map exists, consider its 2nd component: It would be a continuous equivariant map $S^1\to S^2$. But its existence would contradict nondiscreteness of $\rho_2(\Gamma)$. This is another nice exercise. The key is the fact that every sequence of distinct elements of $\Gamma$, when regarded as a sequence of maps $S^1\to S^1$, subconverges to a constant map away from a single point in $S^1$. On the other hand, this property fails for general sequences $(\rho_2(\gamma_n))$ since they may converge to elements of $G_2$ due to lack of discreteness.